# How to order list by nearest value

Tags: java, android, sorting

So i have this small list as follows which represents warehouse locations:

```
30 09 05
30 04 05
30 02 01 
31 07 05 
31 07 04 
31 03 05 
31 03 06 
31 09 05 
31 02 05
```

The first column represents the location row, the second location height and the third the location position (forward)

I need to calculate the optimal path (row, position, height) for a forklift operator to retrieve different items based on different locations

For this I am using Collection.sort to sort the list first by rows then position (forward) and lastly by height.

The rows are grouped by pairs because it makes sense for the operator to retrieve items from the even row (operator left) and odd row (operator right) without moving the fork lift position and height

I am almost there i just need a hand for when the pos moves forward i need to keep the same height and get the nearest height instead of starting at the bottom which makes the operator lose time going up and down

Here is the code:

```
Collections.sort(unoptimizedLocations, new Comparator<ItemOrderLocation>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ItemOrderLocation item1, ItemOrderLocation item2) {

        int rowCmp = item1.row.compareTo(item2.row);
        int heightCmp = item1.height.compareTo(item2.height);
        int posCmp = item1.pos.compareTo(item2.pos);

        int item1Row = Integer.parseInt(item1.row);
        int item2Row = Integer.parseInt(item2.row);

        boolean onForkLiftPath = false;

        if (item1Row == (item2Row + 1) && (item2Row % 2 == 0)) {
            onForkLiftPath = true;
        }

        if (!onForkLiftPath && rowCmp != 0) {
            //Two differents rows which are not on Fork Lift Path
            return rowCmp;
        }

        //If are on forklift path we compare the position
        if (posCmp != 0) {
            return posCmp;
        }

        //Lastly if row is on forklift path and we are on same position we need to sort by nearest height
        return heightCmp;
    }
});
```

With this code the list gets ordered like this:

```
30 02 01 
31 07 04 
31 02 05 
31 03 05 
30 04 05 
31 07 05 
30 09 05 
31 09 05 
31 03 06
```

And for better understanding the final sorted list (nearest height for less height traveling) should look like this:

```
30 02 01 
31 07 04
31 07 05 
30 09 05
31 09 05 
30 04 05
31 03 05    
31 02 05
31 03 06
```

Any ideas how can reach this result using my sorting algorithm?

Comment: is it school assignment?

Comment: No! Why are you asking such question? I tried using arrays to sort everything but it used a lot of memory and also wasn´t an optimal solution

Comment: This problem might better be solved in a non-Collections.sort() approach.  Is that something you would consider, or are you only considering this approach?

Comment: Optimal path, i.e: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem is different than sorting. Is the first entry the starting point and can't be changed?

Comment: @IanMc I am open for different approaches that might solve this problem specifically

Comment: @MorrisonChang The operator can filter by rows in the app like for example if it wants to fetch items to fulfill client orders from row 25 to row 31, the starting position is always the beginning of the lowest row for example in this case it would be 25 01 01 and the algorithm has to calculate which is nearest location (shortest path) with the requested item based on what i wrote

Comment: The input contains 9 locations however the output contains 7 (30 02 01 and 31 03 06 are missing).  Is this an oversite?  If so, can you refresh the correct output to include all 9 locations?  If not, why were they excluded?

Comment: @IanMc Sorry my bad i just updated the examples to have all 9 locations, do you have any idea how can i solve this problem easily?

Comment: Yes.  Are the following statements true about the solution? 1) Within a row pair, the position always increases. 2) A row pair is always completed before moving row pairs 3) The best solution is one where, in the same row and position, the height change is minimized?

Comment: @IanMc that is correct

Comment: OK.  A sort will not work because a comparator can only look at two elements at a time.  This solution requires an algorithm.  Are you looking for help creating the algorithm and you code it?

Comment: @IanMc Yes we could that

Comment: I can help.  Last question:  When the operator moves rows (say 30/31 to 32/33) do they restart at position 1?

Comment: @IanMc Yes that's also correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves the fork lift problem, given the constraints.

```
ALGORITHM
Input:  All locations
Output:  Shortest path given constraints
1.  For all row/pairs, in increasing order
2.  For all positions in that row, in increasing order
3.  For all heights with same row/pair and position, add locations to minimize the height change given a starting height
```

The code uses Java 8 streams.  The code attempts to have single purpose methods; so feel free to rewrite any method in a more familiar syntax.  It is not guaranteed to be optimized, but given the low size of the input, that should not be a concern.  Let me know if you have any questions.

And the code:

```
public class ForkLiftOperator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ForkLiftOperator().start();
}

private void start() {

    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    locations.add(new Location(30, 9, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(30, 4, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(30, 2, 1));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 7, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 7, 4));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 3, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 3, 6));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 9, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(31, 2, 5));
    locations.add(new Location(32, 2, 5));  // Extra to simulate additional row/pair

    List<Location> solution = solve(locations);
    System.out.println(solution);
}


private List<Location> solve(List<Location> locations) {

    List<Location> shortestPath = new ArrayList<Location>();
    int activeRow, activePosition, activeHeight;
    while ((activeRow = getNextRow(locations)) != 0) {
        System.out.println("Working on row="+activeRow);
        List<Location> activeLocations = getLocationsByRowPair(activeRow, locations);
        activePosition = 0;
        activeHeight = 0;
        while ((activePosition = getNextPos(activePosition, activeLocations)) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Working on pos="+activePosition);
            List<Location> activePositionLocations = getLocationsForRowAndPosition(activeRow, activePosition, activeLocations);
            shortestPath.addAll(minimizeHeight(activeHeight, activePositionLocations));
            activeHeight = shortestPath.get(shortestPath.size()-1).height;
        }
    }


    return shortestPath;
}

enum Direction { UP, DOWN }
/**
 * For the given locations (which are guaranteed to be at the same row/position), minimize the total height change
 * @param activePositionLocations The locations at this row/pair and location (they will only differ in height)
 * @return The order will minimize the height change
 */
private List<Location> minimizeHeight(int currentHeight, List<Location> activePositionLocations) {
    List<Location> optimizedHeightLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    System.out.println("Processing locations="+activePositionLocations);
    int minHeight = activePositionLocations.stream().mapToInt(location -> location.height).min().getAsInt();
    int maxHeight = activePositionLocations.stream().mapToInt(location -> location.height).max().getAsInt();
    /*
     * There are only two options to minimize (if the current height falls between min and max):
     * 1)  Travel down then up
     * 2)  Travel up then down
     */
    // First determine the first direction to go
    Direction direction;
    if (currentHeight == minHeight)
        direction = Direction.UP;
    else if (currentHeight == maxHeight)
        direction = Direction.DOWN;
    else {
        int distanceUp = maxHeight-currentHeight;
        int distanceDown = currentHeight-minHeight;
        direction = distanceUp < distanceDown ? Direction.UP : Direction.DOWN;
    }
    // Now travel in that direction (must sort the correct way first
    List<Location> sortedAscending = activePositionLocations.stream().sorted((l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l1.height, l2.height)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Location> sortedDescending = activePositionLocations.stream().sorted((l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l2.height, l1.height)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (direction == Direction.UP) {
        optimizedHeightLocations.addAll(sortedAscending.stream().filter(location -> location.height >= currentHeight).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        optimizedHeightLocations.addAll(sortedDescending.stream().filter(location -> location.height < currentHeight).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } else {    // Direction = DOWN
        optimizedHeightLocations.addAll(sortedDescending.stream().filter(location -> location.height <= currentHeight).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        optimizedHeightLocations.addAll(sortedAscending.stream().filter(location -> location.height > currentHeight).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    return optimizedHeightLocations;
}

/**
 * Determine all the locations for this current row/pair and position
 * @param activeRow The current row/pair
 * @param activePos The current position
 * @param locations The locations for this row/pair
 * @return The locations at this exact row/pair and position
 */
private List<Location> getLocationsForRowAndPosition(int activeRow, int activePos,
        List<Location> locations) {
    int minRow = activeRow;
    int maxRow = ((activeRow & 1) == 0) ? activeRow + 1 : activeRow;    // If even, then pair includes the next higher row
    return locations.stream().filter(location -> location.row >= minRow && location.row <= maxRow && location.position == activePos)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Determine the next position, given the current position
 * @param currentPosition Where the operator is currently
 * @param locations The locations for this row/pair
 * @return The next closest, or zero if they are at the end
 */
private int getNextPos(int currentPosition, List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    OptionalInt min = locations.stream().filter(location -> location.position > currentPosition)
            .mapToInt(location -> location.position)
            .min(); 
    return min.isPresent() ? min.getAsInt() : 0;
}

/**
 * Filter out any locations for this row pair.
 * The locations for this row will be removed from the original list
 * @param nextRow The current row being processed
 * @param locations The remaining locations
 * @return The locations for the active row
 */
private List<Location> getLocationsByRowPair(int nextRow, List<Location> locations) {
    List<Location> activeLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    Iterator<Location> i = locations.iterator();
    int minRow = nextRow;
    int maxRow = ((nextRow & 1) == 0) ? nextRow + 1 : nextRow;  // If even, then pair includes the next higher row
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Location current = i.next();
        if (current.row >= minRow && current.row <= maxRow) {
            activeLocations.add(current);
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    return activeLocations;
}

/**
 * Determine the lowest row from the locations provided
 * @param locations All remaining locations
 * @return The minimum row number remaining
 */
private int getNextRow(List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return locations.stream().mapToInt(location -> location.row)
            .min().getAsInt();
}

class Location {
    final int row;
    final int position;
    final int height;
    public Location(int row, int height, int position) {
        this.row = row;
        this.position = position;
        this.height = height;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + row + ", " + height + ", " + position + "]";
    }

}
```

}

Produces the following output, which matches the desired output:

[[30, 2, 1], [31, 7, 4], [31, 7, 5], [30, 9, 5], [31, 9, 5], [30, 4, 5], [31, 3, 5], [31, 2, 5], [31, 3, 6], [32, 2, 5]]

Here are the Java7 versions of the current Java8 code:

Java8:

```
private List<Location> getLocationsForRowAndPosition(int activeRow, int activePos,
        List<Location> locations) {
    int minRow = activeRow;
    int maxRow = ((activeRow & 1) == 0) ? activeRow + 1 : activeRow;    // If even, then pair includes the next higher row
    return locations.stream().filter(location -> location.row >= minRow && location.row <= maxRow && location.position == activePos)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Java 7:

```
private List<Location> getLocationsForRowAndPosition(int activeRow, int activePos,
        List<Location> locations) {
    int minRow = activeRow;
    int maxRow = ((activeRow & 1) == 0) ? activeRow + 1 : activeRow;    // If even, then pair includes the next higher row
    List<Location> positionLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    for (Location location : locations) {
        if (location.row >= minRow && location.row <= maxRow && location.position == activePos)
            positionLocations.add(location);
    }
    return positionLocations;
}
```

Java 8:

```
private int getNextPos(int currentPosition, List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    OptionalInt min = locations.stream().filter(location -> location.position > currentPosition)
            .mapToInt(location -> location.position)
            .min(); 
    return min.isPresent() ? min.getAsInt() : 0;
}
```

Java 7:

```
private int getNextPos(int currentPosition, List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Location location : locations) {
        if (location.position > currentPosition && location.position < minValue)
            minValue = location.position;
    }
    return minValue == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? 0 : minValue;
}
```

Java 8:

```
private int getNextRow(List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    return locations.stream().mapToInt(location -> location.row)
            .min().getAsInt();
}
```

Java 7:

```
private int getNextRow(List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty())
        return 0;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Location location : locations) {
        if (location.row < minValue)
            minValue = location.row;
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

And last the Java 7 for minimizeHeight:

```
private List<Location> minimizeHeight(int currentHeight, List<Location> activePositionLocations) {
    List<Location> optimizedHeightLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    int minHeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxHeight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Location location : activePositionLocations) {
        if (location.height < minHeight)
            minHeight = location.height;
        if (location.height > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = location.height;
    }

    /*
     * There are only two options to minimize (if the current height falls between min and max):
     * 1)  Travel down then up
     * 2)  Travel up then down
     */
    // First determine the first direction to go
    Direction direction;
    if (currentHeight == minHeight)
        direction = Direction.UP;
    else if (currentHeight == maxHeight)
        direction = Direction.DOWN;
    else {
        int distanceUp = maxHeight-currentHeight;
        int distanceDown = currentHeight-minHeight;
        direction = distanceUp < distanceDown ? Direction.UP : Direction.DOWN;
    }
    // Now travel in that direction (must sort the correct way first
    List<Location> sortedAscending = new ArrayList<Location>(activePositionLocations);  // Clone it
    Collections.sort(sortedAscending, new Comparator<Location>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Location l1, Location l2) {
            return Integer.compare(l1.height, l2.height);
        }
    });
    List<Location> sortedDescending = new ArrayList<Location>(activePositionLocations); // Clone it
    Collections.sort(sortedDescending, new Comparator<Location>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Location l1, Location l2) {
            return Integer.compare(l2.height, l1.height);
        }
    });

    if (direction == Direction.UP) {
        for (Location location : sortedAscending) {
            if (location.height >= currentHeight)
                optimizedHeightLocations.add(location);
        }
        for (Location location : sortedDescending) {
            if (location.height < currentHeight)
                optimizedHeightLocations.add(location);
        }
    } else {    // Direction = DOWN
        for (Location location : sortedDescending) {
            if (location.height <= currentHeight)
                optimizedHeightLocations.add(location);
        }
        for (Location location : sortedAscending) {
            if (location.height > currentHeight)
                optimizedHeightLocations.add(location);
        }
    }

    return optimizedHeightLocations;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code it works wonderfully on Android API 24 and above but i need to make this work for at least API 21 (Lollipop) which doesn´t support java 8 streams. Now i am trying to convert your code to use https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport and RetroLambada. If you have any guidance to achieve this please let me know

Comment: I can change the Streams to normal loops.  That might be easier.  I find Streams makes more concise code, but it isn't too difficult to write pre-Streams code.  I have no experience with RetroLambada - sorry. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I tried using normal loops to solve this problem but couldn´t figure it out how, so i would love to see how could you achieve the same result using loops. If you would be kind to do so please leave two examples one using streams as it is and other using loops.

Comment: No problem.  I'll be busy the next few hours but will post something later tonight.  If you don't mind, I think I'll create a second answer rather than clutter the first one.

Comment: I don't mind at all. By the way i forgot an important detail which is if the row is lower then 30 the pair is (odd number, even number) so the warehouse is organized like this row pairs are (1,2) (3,4) until it gets to 30 then the pair switchs to a (even,odd) pair starts which starts like (30,31). I tried changing your getLocationsRowPair to accommodate this particular case but i am now getting NoSuchElementException

Comment: Oh i noticed that you are also checking in getLocationsForRowAndPosition if the activeRow is even so checking if activeRow is lower then 30 and odd on both methods solved this new user case! I will wait for your answer for how to implement this in normal loops Thanks again

Comment: Steve - Nice job fixing the row/pair case where row<30.  The code above does not have that fix.  The answer has been edited to include all the Java7 code.  I have tested this, and it works the same.  I hope I didn't miss any Java 8 code.  Good luck with your project.  Cheers.

Comment: Just checked your Java 7 code i can see now that Java 8 Streams are easier to read so i decided to make you java 8 code compatible for android lollipop for this i just needed to replace your Java 8 Stream code with Lightweight-Stream-API and works wonderfully. By the way can i assume that using streams improves performance? Also how could i improve this sample for bigger inputs? Thanks again

Comment: Ok just found a small bug in the ordering algorithm which ordered the list like this:

[[15 3 7],[16 8 8], [16 8 8], [15 6 8], [16 6 8], [16 6 8], [16 3 8],[16 3 8],[15 1 9]]

When switching position from 7 to 8 (last number) while height is 3 the list goes up to height 8 and goes back down back to 3 while it should have ordered the items at height 3 together i am now trying to solve this problem with your java 8 code

Comment: I just found out something weird with the algorithm, if the list is really big with a lot of locations i am seeing the final order listed from row 1 until row 15 then going back to row 1 here is an image: https://imgur.com/a/mK0K8. Also before it goes back to row 1 you can see when it switched from pos 13 to 15 it went from height 9 to 1 and then back to 9

The algorithm seems to work fine with small lists with bigger lists it starts behaving weirdly any thoughts why?

Comment: Hi again I have to apologize there isn´t any issue with the row ordering i was mistakenly seeing two logs from different times so they were different ordered lists. About the issue with the heights i fixed it by adding a check in your minimizeHeight function where i filter the original list by height == currentHeight and add to optimizedHeightItemOrderLocations before adding the desc and ascending halfs. It now seems to work properly if you could answer the last two questions about stream performance and how it can be optimized that would be awesome thanks again

Comment: No worries.  About performance: Streams will perform better, because streams can run input across multiple processors (when that makes sense) - for example finding a minimum in a List is 'stateless' and can run in parallel. Do large inputs take a long time to run?  Can you give an example of how big an input might be?  I just want to be clear on what you mean by 'optimized' - thanks.